# BuildConfig prop for each buildType / productFlavor combination

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors, buildconfig

I have free and paid versions of an app. I need to configure with gradle a prop on BuildConfig that is different for each buildType / productFlavor combination.

- free-debug -> prop1=value1
- free-release -> prop1=value2
- paid-debug -> prop1=value3
- paid-release -> prop1=value4

My build types are debug / release, and my product flavors are free / paid

Could you help me with this?

Comment: AFAIK, you will need to iterate over the variants and set them that way. See the release notes for 0.14.3 at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system.

Comment: I have the exact same requirement and I am madly looking for a solution, that does not involve manipulating the manifest file inside the Build-Dir. How is it that Google and Android did not think of this? They do not have Debuggable Settings versions for their Android Apps in any of their Lower-lane Test-Services and Server-Environments?