# BuildConfig Constants for buildType per each productFlavors in Gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have two applications have single base code in **main folder**  and each application have three types of buildTypes call **debug**, **preview** and **release**. So I created

***two*** productFlavors i.e App1, App2

***three*** buildTypes i.e debu,preview and release

but each application has ***different URLs for different build types***

my project structure is like

[image]

what I tried

**build.gradle file**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ksp.com.buidflavourspoc"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
//
        }
        preview {
//
        }
        release {
            keyAlias 'test'
            keyPassword 'test'
            storePassword 'test'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        def BOOLEAN = "boolean";
        def TRUE = "true";
        def FALSE = "false";
        def IS_LOG = "IS_LOG";
        debug {
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, IS_LOG, FALSE
        }
        preview {
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, IS_LOG, FALSE
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, IS_LOG, TRUE
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        app1 {
            applicationId ".com.android.app1"
            buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"http://app1curl.com"'
        }
        app2 {
            applicationId ".com.android.app2"
            buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"app2url.com"'
        }

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

With this, I can get URL's based on product flavor (`like BuildConfig.HOST`) but I can't get **APP1debug HOST** separate if I select**APP1debug**

**How can I relates both ??** i.e I want to get debug URL for APP1 from Gradle if I select **APP1debug**

like

[image]

I have gone through [BuildConfig prop for each buildType](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27405301/5955593) but did not find the solution.

Welcome any suggestions from Android community.

I am thinking like

```
 productFlavors {
            app1 {
                applicationId ".com.android.app1"
               if(buildTypes.DEBUG){
                buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"http://app1curldebug.com"'
}else{
 buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"http://app1curlpreview.com"'
}
            }
            app2 {
                applicationId ".com.android.app2"
                if(buildTypes.DEBUG){
                buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"app2urldebug.com"'
}else{
 buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"app2urlpreview.com"'
}
            }
```

But don't know how to use if conditions in build.gradle file !

Comment: lets URL = URL_PART + HOST ... now define HOST(as you did) in flavor and URL_PART in type

Comment: Can elaborate please?

Comment: there is nothing to elaborate ... what do you not understand string concatenation?

Comment: if I choose App1release >> I want to get one BuildConfig.HOST_FOR_APP1_RELEASE from Gradle ? It is possible with your solution ?

Comment: No,  it is not.. it is not possible at all

Comment: @Selvin Thanks, What I am thinking is If I declare buildTypes inside each productFlavour so I can get this done but I dint know how to do this.